# Trying to fill an array when a submit button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I've created a timer which has a submit button. This submit button only populates one slot of an array, it doesn't sequentially populate each slot on each click.

Currently I have it set up using a .push within the submit button function. This is where I think I'm going wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

const ms = require('pretty-ms');

class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      time: 0,
      start: 0,
      isOn: false, 

    }
    this.onItemMouseDown = this.onItemMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.onItemMouseUp = this.onItemMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  onItemMouseDown() {
    this.setState({
      time: this.state.time,
      start: Date.now() - this.state.time,
      isOn: true
    })

    //the below uses a predefined function setInterval with a nested arrow function setting the state again 
    // which is time. More detail: It compares the time to the current date and time for accuracy. The interval is 1.
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState({
      time: Date.now() - this.state.start
    }), 1);


  }

  onItemMouseUp() {
    this.setState({isOn: false});
    clearInterval(this.timer);   
  }


  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({time: 0})
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const scoreArray = [];

    scoreArray.push(ms(this.state.time))

    console.log(scoreArray)

  }

  render() {

    if((this.state.isOn) === true){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h3>timer: {ms(this.state.time)} </h3>

      </div>
    <div>
      <button onMouseDown={this.onItemMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.onItemMouseUp} >start</button>    

      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>reset</button> 

      </div>

      </React.Fragment>
    ) 
    } else {  

      return(
        <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h3>Your time is: {ms(this.state.time)}</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
      <button onMouseDown={this.onItemMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.onItemMouseUp}>Start</button>  <span></span>  

      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button> <span></span>

      <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Done!</button>
      </div>     
      </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }

}


export default Timer

  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, rootElement);
```

The submit button should then populate each array slot with a time value on each click. 
I tend to overthink things. Is there a better alternative? 
My ultimate goal is to populate the array and then (for educational purposes) display that array in JSX as a score/time list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scoreArray` data does not persist in your `component`. As currently constructed you are just reinitializing the array every time you call `onSubmit`. You can store it as a state-value instead.

### In your state-definition

```
this.state = {
  time: 0,
  start: 0,
  isOn: false, 
  scoreArray: []
}
```

### In onSubmit()

```
  onSubmit() {
    const { scoreArray } = this.state;

    this.setState({
       ...this.state,
       scoreArray: [...scoreArray, (ms(this.state.time))]
    } () => console.log(this.state.scoreArray))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I'm trying to solve this using the state-definition, but I'm getting errors. I'm using:
this.setState(this.state.scoreArray.push(ms(this.state.time)))
within the onSubmit()
 Can you provide a solution?

Comment: @Tom, you should never mutate component-state. Avoid doing something like this.state.scoreArray.push(). This often leads to unwanted functionality in your component. Try using a spread-operator like the above :)

Comment: @Tom, is the above solution not working for you? :o

Comment: Hi Christopher - that's great. Thanks for your answers. Upvoted and answered.